# Laravel Get 10 Post that Most Voted Yesterday

Tags: mysql, laravel, sorting, relationship

i want get 10 post that most voted yesterday. according laravel official doc and other questions that answered here, i use bellow code :

```
$tops = Post::where('type' , 'albums')->withCount('Rates')->orderByDesc('rates_count')->take(10)->get();
```

and Relation :

```
public function Rates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rate::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Post Table :

---

| id | type | slug | view_day | view_week | view_month | status | created_at | updated_at |

---

Rates Table :

---

| id | parent_id | ip| rate | created_at | updated_at |

---

it's Work but **it take so long**. as you see in bellow images when use *orderByDesc('rates_count')* compare without this, there is big time difference.

[image: With Count - 36s take time]
With Count - 36s take time

[image: Without Count - less than 1s]
Without Count - less than 1s

so any body know another optimized method

Comment: Have you indexed? And I am not sure if the results are correct with these codes?

Comment: what part of code you mean ?
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I would optimize that using joins

Comment: Take command skips 10 rows and fetch data. I don't understand why you use.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Post & Rate Table Schema Added